# pandas difference between to data frame according to custom rules

Tags: python, pandas

This is simplified example of what I want to do:

```
data1 = {'one':['A', 'E', 'G'], 'two':['B', 'D', 'H'], 'three':['C', 'F', 'J']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 
df1

   one  two three
0   A   B   C
1   E   D   F
2   G   H   J

data2 = {'one':['C', 'F', 'P'], 'two':['B', 'D', 'R'], 'three':['A', 'E', 'C']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2) 
df2

    one two three
0   C   B   A
1   F   D   E
2   P   R   C
```

I want a function the will show me something like this:

```
diff(df1, df2) # this syntaks can be different

    one two three  from
0   G   H   J      df1
1   P   R   C      df2
```

Basically find came text for column two in both dataFrames, and if one and three columns are reversed, then it is fine, do not add it in a new frame.

I know how to do it with a loop but would like to know what is panda way of doing this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`pandas.Index.symmetric_difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.symmetric_difference.html)

```
df1.set_index(df1.apply(frozenset, 1), inplace=True)
df2.set_index(df2.apply(frozenset, 1), inplace=True)

df1['from'] = 'df1'
df2['from'] = 'df2'

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).loc[df1.index ^ df2.index].reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  one three two from
0   G     J   H  df1
1   P     C   R  df2
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple enought, just compare the columns that you want to be the same and filter on that. In your example:

```
pd.concat([df.loc[df1["two"] != df2["two"]] for df in (df1, df2)], axis=0)
```

EDIT: if you want the "from" column as well, change the above line to:

```
pd.concat([df.loc[df1["two"] != df2["two"]].assign(from_df=df_name) for df, df_name in zip((df1, df2), ("df1", df2)], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, for effort. FYI your code is only working if there are the same number of row in dataFrame. I gave you upvote.

Comment: fair point, I guess the symmetric difference is the way to go here